# Report Builder - Open a link to a new browser window with dynamic URL

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

In report builder (SSRS) I have a parent report with a link via order_no to open a drill through child report. Is there a way to make the expression dynamic specifically the URL so it will call the report server where the Parent report is running?  What happen to my report is that it was working fine in UAT because my existing setting is in UAT. Once I uploaded it to PROD, the parent report was ok but it was still re-directing to UAT for the child report.

="javascript:void window.open('http://UATSERVER/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Order/Reports/Orderdetails" &
"&unit=" & Fields!Order_NO.Value &
"&rs:Command=Render','_blank')"

Tried other scripts I found in the other's advise but still no avail. My work around is to just edit the PROD with the PROD servername.

Comment: if the child link is pointing to UAT they why would you expect it to go to your prod server? Your link is hardcoded with the UATSERVER.. what did you try btw?

Comment: yeah, that's why I am trying to find a way how to make the URL dynamic in a way that it will get the parent's servername. I found in some posts about this sample expression they show but I don't know if this is what I need and I can't make it work.
=”javascript:void(window.open(‘” & LCase(Globals!ReportServerUrl) & “?” & Replace(LCase(Globals!ReportServerUrl),”/_vti_bin/reportserver”,””)  & “/ProjectBICenter/SSRS Reports Library/Project Overall Status.rdl&ParmProjectName=” & LCase(Fields!ProjectUID_STR.Value) & “‘,’_blank’));”

Comment: you just need the PRODSERVER name insted of UATSERVER right.. why not just select @@SERVERNAME in SQL and then pass that into the link instead?

Comment: It returns my db server name not the report server name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=Globals!ReportServerUrl` in your expression. This will return the server URL in the format

`http://myServerName/ReportServer`

This will only work when the report is deployed to the server, so it will return nothing when you run the report from Visual Studio etc.

From you comments it looks like you are trying to point to the `_vti_bin` folder but that does not make sense, that folder will not be on the server and it you are in your dev environment then there is no report server to reference.